# google play uses wrong account for in-app purchases

Tags: google-play-store, in-app-purchase

Problem:
When trying to purchase in-app items, google play selects the wrong google account and do not allow the user to correct it.

Scenario:
I have two google accounts, one private and one business. The private account is the default in google play when buying and installing apps. Though when trying an in-app purchase, the business account is choosen and cannot be changed. In my case, this prohibits me in-app purchases.

Further notes:
Uninstalling/reinstalling app to be sure the correct account is used in google play has no affect.

Haven't tried removing the business account and see how it affects the in-app purchases as I'm reluctant to do so. (Other way around would have been better:)

Question:
Have you encountered this problem and found a way to resolve/work-around it?

Comment: The question asked here is indeed very similar to the one referred to as its duplicate, with one difference though; the app in this case is installed via google play direcly and not side loaded via APK. The referred to question does not contain a workable solution, with exception for removing all but the wished for account. From my investigation so far, this is a bug in google play's in-app purchase, or the in-app purchase in some apps (some apps are strangly enough directed to the correct account), one crude workaround is available as earler stated.

Comment: I tried to add this info as complementary info to the other case before posting question, though due to the 50 rep minimum for being allowed to comment, I was not allowed to do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had a similar problem. What I did was completely reset my device, and then only associate my business account with it. That way my Gmail App is only displaying business conversations only. This also has the benefit of not confusing Play Store. This isn't the best way to do this probably, but it works. If you need to check your personal account, just sign in through your browser. This also prevents prying eyes from looking through your gmail app and seeing something personal.